# Enqueued from com.apple.main-thread (Thread 1) Crash | iOS | Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm, grand-central-dispatch

[image: Reference image showing crash]

What's happening above:

1. Initialize realm model from the received array of user data.
2. Write all the models at once in the realm DB in the background thread.
3. Realm model is getting updated if they already exist by creating a copy.

Can anyone please guide me here about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Perform only UI Operation in DispatchQueue.main.async same issue as previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646177/crash-when-saving-data-to-realm-in-background-thread-ios-swift-4-2/55646342?noredirect=1#comment98083582_55646342

Comment: It's not safe (actually it's an error) to use Realm objects across multiple threads. This may be your problem here. See this advice on how to pass a Realm object to a background thread: https://realm.io/docs/cookbook/swift/object-to-background/ You may not be able to use the recipe directly, but it sould give you the idea on what to do...

Comment: @Peeyush Please updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646177/crash-when-saving-data-to-realm-in-background-thread-ios-swift-4-2/55646342?noredirect=1#comment98083582_55646342

Comment: @Lutz Sorry! Thanks and comments deleted

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem. Here you might be accessing realm object from different thread. For eg: You can use the dispatch queue, but there is a higher chance that the object you are trying to access is declared in another thread. You can have a realm object in any thread, but accessing a property of this realm object will lead to a crash. In my case, I was accessing an array of realm objects from a singleton which is initialized inside a different thread. Even if I added DispatchQueue closure it caused an error because the objects which I tried to access were in another thread.